# how to print all the elements present in data frame to the console in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains 11,000 rows in it. But if I print the data frame as print (df), only the first 50 elements are printed in the console and will get the following error:

```
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 10456 rows ]
```

hence i have used

```
options(max.print = 999999999)
```

this will print all the 11,000 rows, but in console when scrolling from the bottom, I am able to scroll only till 9500 row. Is there anyway that I can scroll all the 11,000 rows in console?

Comment: Are u printing it to console to view specific rows? If that's the case you can also use `View(df)`.

Comment: try outputting it to a file instead

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R but sometimes view works and sometimes it shows error like function view does not exist

Comment: @Srinivas maybe you mistakenly wrote `view()` which does not exist. The V has to be capitalized.

Comment: @Base_R_Best_R  yes your right,thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

You can try increasing the **scrolling value** and then you can able to scroll up to whatever you are set.

e.g: in the Linux terminal, see the below picture:

[image]