# R print all rows of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

What's the most R-way to print all the rows of a data.frame?

[print.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.dataframe.html) has a `max` option, but it cannot be set to `Inf`.

```
Error in print.data.frame(macrodf2, max = Inf) : 
  invalid 'max' / getOption("max.print"): Inf
```

Comment: have you tried `print.data.frame(macrodf2, max = NULL)`?

Comment: It would be somewhat cumbersome to view infinitely many rows on the console. Are you using the console output for something other than just viewing results? There are better ways to view large data sets. You could always just set it to print all entries: `print(dd, max=nrow(dd)*ncol(dd))` maybe create an alias for that with `print_all <- function(data, max=nrow(data)*ncol(data), ...) print(dd, max=max, ...)`. (Note this can take a long time print)

Comment: @Pasqui From the `?print.data.frame` help page, if you set `max=NULL` it will use the value of `getOption("max.print")` which is by default 1,000. It will not print all rows.

Comment: @camille [print.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.dataframe.html) has no `n` option

Comment: Note that inmost cases the Console actually can't even scroll back very far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589073/how-to-print-all-the-elements-present-in-data-frame-to-the-console-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick You're right, I use too many tibbles! The `print` method there gets an `n` argument passed

Comment: @robertspierre yes, I was thinking of it as the fact that `print` is a generic, so different object types will have different `print` methods. Unfortunately, the `n` argument I was thinking of was for the `tibble` print method, not the base `data.frame` one

Comment: @MrFlick sorry I understood you've already edited getOptions (BTW max.print:
integer, defaulting to 99999, not 1k. R3.6.3. If this is true on your R version too, it rules out Inf which is not of type integer).